# Get nodes and group them based on specific inputs from user

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

I have a binary tree. 
Each node is a struct with the 2 values: width and length.

The input from the user is to group them based on one or both criteria(height, width).
For this grouping, only the leaf nodes are considered.
Consider the tree in the attached image.
[image]
If the user said group based on length, the result would be [8,5,7] as it has a length 20 and [9,6] as its length is 10.

If the user said group based on both length and width, then the output would be 
[8,5] *w=20,l=30* ,  [9,6] *l=10,w=20* ,  [7] *l=20,w=10* .

How I dealt with this was to traverse the tree twice and collect 2 'lists of lists' and process that to get a new 'lists of lists' that groups the unique l&w values together.

The user can optionally also give level as an input. If the level is given as an input, then the same steps happen at that level instead of at leaf nodes.

Is there a better way to do it than what I have mentioned?
PS. I am working on this code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

**Data:**

Construct a list of objects with fields

- length
- width
- level

You can create this "main" list by doing a level-order traversal.

and construct the following lists from the main list:

- a length-level-sorted list : list that is sorted first by length and then level
- a width-level-sorted list : list that is sorted first by width and then level
- a length-width-level-sorted list : list that is sorted first by length and then width and then level

**Queries ( log n ):**

- For length queries : do a binary search on length-level-sorted list and look for all the objects to the left of found index and right index and return the group - should be `O(log(n))`
- For width queries : do the same on width-level-sorted list - should be `O(log(n))`
- For length and width queries : do binary search on length-width-level-sorted list first by length and then by width - should be `O(log(n))`
- For level option : if level is included in query in any of the above queries - just do binary search by level - should be `O(log(n))` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not clear to me what you mean by "sorted first by length and then level". If you sort the list the second time for a different parameter won't the first sort become redundant?

Comment: consider this list : (l=10, w=30, level=2), (l=10, w= 10,level=1), (l=5, w=15,level=3) "sorted first by length and then level" means it will first the list by length resulting in : (l=5, w=15, level=3), (l=10,w=30,level=2) , (l=10, w=10, level=1) and then it sorts by length resulting in : (l=5, w=15, level=3), (l=10, w=10, level=1), (l=10, w=30, level=2) so it changes only when there is a tie between lengths otherwise not.